# Wrap a Ruby function

Tags: ruby

I want to be able to completely transparently wrap any Ruby proc (including ones that I have not written the source code for myself), and log its execution time.

```
my_proc
```

That is, I want to create a proc that calls `my_proc` preserving

1. the context/receiver
2. the arguments
3. the block.

and print out the execution time when it was called.

---

For example:

```
my_proc = proc { |*args, &block| p self: self, args: args, block: block }

Object.new.instance_eval &my_proc
#=> {
#  :self=>#<Object:0x007fd4c985f3e0>,
#  :args=>[#<Object:0x007fd4c985f3e0>],
#  :block=>nil
# }

Object.instance_exec '5', &my_proc
#=> {
#  :self=>Object,
#  :args=>["5"],
#  :block=>nil
# }

my_proc.call(1, 2) { }
#=> {
#  :self=>main,
#  :args=>[1, 2],
#  :block=>#<Proc:0x007fd4c985e9b8>
# }
```

And then I want to wrap it, and it should behave exactly the same:

```
def wrap(prc)
  # what does this look like?
end

wrapped_proc = wrap(my_proc)

Object.new.instance_eval(&wrapped_proc)
# took 1s
#=> {
#  :self=>#<Object:0x007fd4c985f3e0>,
#  :args=>[#<Object:0x007fd4c985f3e0>],
#  :block=>nil
# }

Object.instance_exec '5', &wrapped_proc
# took 2s
#=> {
#  :self=>Object,
#  :args=>["5"],
#  :block=>nil
# }

wrapped_proc.call(1, 2) { }
# took 3s
#=> {
#  :self=>main,
#  :args=>[1, 2],
#  :block=>#<Proc:0x007fd4c985e9b8>
# }
```

---

It doesn't seem like a transparent function wrapper should be hard, but I can't figure this out.

Comment: You code doesn't work for me. Do you mean `p self, args, block` and `instance_eval(&wrapped_proc)`? And you probably want `my_proc` instead of `wrapped_proc` in your first example.

Comment: Nah, I give up. it's either receiver or the block. I couldn't pass all three.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev you must be kidding. Of course this question (still being absurd) has an answer: `def wrap(λ); λ; end`.

Comment: @mudasobwa: inspect my answer edit history. This was the first thing I posted. However, it does not qualify as __wrapping__.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev why is that? OK, for so picky you: does the following qualify as wrapping? `def wrap(λ); λ.dup; end`? :)

Comment: @mudasobwa: no, that's cloning :) You surely are familiar with concept of decorators. That is wrapping. Get a new object (new identity) but some functionality is delegated to the wrapped object.

Comment: @mudasobwa: `my_proc = proc {}; wrapper = proc { my_proc.call }` - something along these lines.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev OMG. `class W; def initialize(λ); @λ = λ; end; def to_proc; @λ; end; def call(*args); @λ.(*args); end; end;` Now?

Comment: Yep, something like this. Does it work according to requirement of the question? :)

Comment: Of course it does. Yet, it’s still a `Delegate` pattern, meaning it still has zero value in this particular case.

Comment: I won’t multiply an entropy by posting absurdness.

Comment: I cannot even reproduce the OP's *unwrapped* examples.

Comment: @JörgWMittag nobody could, please see my first comment here. Also, nobody is able to reproduce an intent.

Comment: @Stefan, sorry. I fixed the typos in the examples.

Comment: @mudasobwa, I meant wrapping in the usual sense. Question clarified. But how does Delegate solve wrapping a proc?

Comment: I do not understand this question. What’s wrong with both examples I have provided here in comments? Both (one with simple proc and another with a class implementing `to_proc` and `call`) perfectly suit the needs specified in OP. _Edit_: `s/both/all three/g`.

Comment: @mudasobwa : Your W class is fine and seems to answer the question.

Comment: @EricDuminil and what’s wrong with `def wrap(λ); λ; end` that _also perfectly answers the question_?

Comment: @mudasobwa, that is not a wrapper. That is an identity. As for `W`, it has the same problem. `def to_proc; @λ; end` I can't intercept the call. I should evidently reword my question. Would it be more clear if I asked for a way to passing the current receiver, arguments, and block to a proc?

Comment: @mudasobwa, I want to proxy and log the execution time of any proc, even if I haven't been the one to write the proc's source code.

Comment: @PaulDraper _that_ sounds like a practical, answerable problem +1

Comment: OK, _now_ I understand the intent.

Answer (score 3):

The only trick here is to handle both `λ.call` and `&λ` pass-through-block cases because in the latter scenario *the `Proc#call` is not invoked*. Sic.

My first [wrong] intent was to simply:

```
def wrap λ
  λ.singleton_class.prepend(Module.new do
    def call(*args, &cb)
      puts "⇓⇓⇓"
      super
      puts "⇑⇑⇑"
    end
  end)
end
```

but as I have already said, the [`specific_eval`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/vm_eval.c#L1639) does not call `Proc#call` nor `Proc#to_proc` and I gave up.

---

On the other hand, we might simply `instance_exec` wrapped λ in the context of the receiver, but there is no way to pass a block *as a parameter* to `instance_exec`, since it already receives λ itself.

The plot thickens. Since we can’t pass a block as a parameter to `instance_exec`, neither can the consumer of our wrapper. Yes, that solves the task:

```
def wrap λ
  -> (*args, &cb) do
    puts "⇓⇓⇓"
    (cb ? λ.call(*args, &cb) : instance_exec(*args, &λ)).tap do |result|
      puts result.inspect
      puts "⇑⇑⇑"
    end
  end
end
```

Here you go.

Comment: "neither can the consumer of our wrapper" - Ah! How did I not think of that!

Comment: @SergioTulentsev frankly, I am still digging into the ruby code (code of ruby itself :), trying to understand what was the reason to bypass `Proc#call` within `&λ` calls. And I can not find any. The first snippet I posted makes way more sense to me.

Comment: Nice solution, and the first try would have made sense. Is UTF-8 code being used in big official Ruby projects?

Comment: "neither can the consumer of our wrapper" Not quite true. We can pass self, arg, and block, if we modify the self object. `a = Object.new; a.define_singleton_method :foo, λ; a.λ(arg) {}`

Comment: @EricDuminil “Is UTF-8 code being used in big official Ruby projects?”—yes, why not? I can’t say for all the official projects, of course, but I personally find it very declarative and handy and push into some _big official projects_.

Comment: @PaulDraper your code seems to never be syntax correct from the first attempt. `NameError: undefined local variable or method `λ' for main:Object`.

Comment: I suppose it makes sense, thanks. Still, after 25 years of programming with only ASCII characters and countless hours of debugging because someone had to use a filename with é, ß or ü, it might take a while for me to adapt. By big official projects, I was thinking about Ruby and Rails for example.

Comment: @mudasobwa, yes, I am new to Ruby. Rather, `a.foo(arg) {}`

Comment: @EricDuminil Mike Perham’s [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq.rb#L53) is a big official project. Yes, it’s still more of a joke there, but in my experience (linux/ext{2,4}) I never met any problems with UTF8 since 2000 and I constantly introduce these symbols into our company’s codebase. E.g. using `⚐` and `⚑` as “alert method name,” `✎` for internal log and `❤` for `OK` status makes my code both freaky and lovely. Also, rails uses `✓` as a value for UTF-8 in `params` of _every single request_, check your logs :)

Comment: @PaulDraper I don’t follow. The code above passes all the tests you’ve provided. Either provide the test that is not passed for the code above, or please restate your question in Layman’s terms.

Comment: @mudasobwa, yes it does pass the examples. I was just thinking of ways the functions could be invoked that wouldn't be transparent.

Comment: @PaulDraper you might want to re-read the answer, it contains _a proof_ of why there are not such ways.