# How proc is executed when passed to `instance_exec`

Tags: ruby, lambda, metaprogramming, proc

The question is inspired by [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40669944/wrap-a-ruby-function/40683924).

`Proc::new` has an option to be called without a block inside a method:

> `Proc::new` may be called without a block only within a method with an attached block, in which case that block is converted to the `Proc` object.

When the `proc`/`lambda` instance is passed as a code block, the new instance of `Proc` is being created:

```
Proc.singleton_class.prepend(Module.new do
  def new(*args, &cb)
    puts "PROC #{[block_given?, cb, *args].inspect}"
    super
  end
end)

Proc.prepend(Module.new do
  def initialize(*args, &cb)
    puts "INIT #{[block_given?, cb, *args].inspect}"
    super
  end
  def call(*args, &cb)
    puts "CALL #{[block_given?, cb, *args].inspect}"
    super
  end
end)

λ = ->(*args) { }
[1].each &λ
#⇒ [1]
```

As one might see, neither the call to `Proc::new` happened, nor `Proc#initialize` and/or `Proc#call` were called.

The question is: **how ruby creates and executes a block wrapper under the hood?**

---

**NB** Don’t test the code above in `pry`/`irb` console: they known to have glitches with pure execution of this, basically because they patch procs.

Comment: @fl00r MRI 2.1–2.3, I actually believe all versions are acting the same here.

Comment: I can't receive your output `ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-darwin14]` I got `[1].each &λ; => [1]`

Comment: `ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin15]`. `[1].each &λ` #=> `[1]`

Comment: OK, it turned out the output I received was `pry`-related. Anyway, the question remains.

Comment: Looks like `Proc#call` is called https://gist.github.com/andreydeineko/ee1dd7506c634845d3174fc3430b4bd3

Comment: @AndreyDeineko this is `pry` glitch; the same reason forced me to think `Proc::new` is called. Copy-paste this code into some file and `ruby file.rb` it.

Answer (score 2):

There has been some discussion of this behavior on the Ruby Issue Tracker, see [Feature #10499: *Eliminate implicit magic in `Proc.new` and `Kernel#proc`*](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10499).

This is an implementation artifact of YARV: YARV pushes a block on the global VM stack, and `Proc::new` simply creates a `Proc` from the topmost block on the stack. So, if you happen to call `Proc.new` from within a method which was called with a block, it will happily grab whatever block is on top of the stack, without ever checking where it came from. Somehow, somewhere, in the mist of time, this (let's call it) "accidental artifact" (I'd actually rather call it a bug) became a documented feature. A feature that the developers of JRuby (and presumably Rubinius, Opal, MagLev, etc.) would rather get rid of.

Since most other implementations work completely differently, this behavior which comes "for free" on YARV, makes both blocks and `Proc::new` pontetially more expensive on other implementations and prohibits possible optimizations (which doesn't hurt on YARV, because YARV doesn't optimize).

Comment: “YARV pushes a pointer to the block on the VM stack”—this looks pretty much as a half of an answer to my question. Does it mean that 1) any other ruby implementation calls `Proc::new` for `[1].each &λ` and 2) the developer has no ability to interfere `[1].each &λ` in YARV, since there is no `Proc` instance created at all? AFAIU, whether the stack happens to contain a block as a “first to out,” YARV would happily execute it bypassing any other ruby code/wrappers/whatever, right?

Comment: Not sure. My answer was based on a fuzzy memory of a one-line post by Charles Nutter, which I now found and linked to in my answer. It doesn't, however, explain how e.g. JRuby does it.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I would appreciate if you have your answer updated with “whatever solution might be applied there to intervene the block passing to method, it does not seem to be cross-VM implementation.”